# How to say what I want to say

Tags: word-choice

I want to say:

> On a surface, making $$$ per years looks like a lot of money. But when you divide it by the actual hours worked, suddenly ***it doesn't look like much.***

Something tells me that the emphasised part might be incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment.

Comment: It might be helpful to say why you think its incorrect.

Comment: "It doesn't look like much" is in question here.

Comment: The sentence is fine. You may be troubled about the apparently ambiguous reference of *it*, but the intent is clear - $$$$$$$ looks a lot smaller when it is considered as $/hr. I have no trouble with the sentence.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but given all the recent publicity re "telephone number" incomes for bankers, directors, etc., I'm inclined to think of *a lot of money* as being orders of magnitude greater than whatever OP has in mind. It would be physically impossible for most of us to work more than 2-3 times more hours than we actually do, so we're not exactly talking about *that* great a difference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ""A billion here, a billion there, pretty soon, you're talking real money." -Everett Dirksen

Comment: @StoneyB: Actually, when I first started working for myself I really did work 70-80 hours a week. Coupling that to the fact that I did mostly "fixed price" jobs where my estimates didn't always match reality, I often used to think I was earning less per hour than our 4-hours-a-week home help. I used to console myself with the idea that eventually I'd accumulate an "asset value" in the business itself, but somehow that never quite worked out.

Answer (score 1):

As a set phrase, I would say "on *the* surface". I have never heard "on *a* surface" used this way. It means a simple, not in depth consideration.
And its *per year* not *per years*.

Not your question but anyway... Then:

> On *the* surface, making $$$ per *year* looks like a lot of money. But when you divide it by the actual hours worked, suddenly it doesn't look like much.

This is OK as is. You could also say:

> ...suddenly it doesn't *seem* like much.

Comment: There's no doubt OP's *"on **a** surface"* is completely wrong. But to be honest, I'm not overkeen on *"on the surface"* (or *"superficially"*, either) in this exact context. I'd much prefer *"**at first glance**"* here. I've no preference between *look/seem*, but I'd be happier with ***so** much*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Doesn't look like much* is sound US idiom - it's not a comparison but a ‘positive’, equivalent to *doesn’t look like a lot*.

Comment: @StoneyB: Yeah - it's the same in BrE. But purely for the sake of "elegance", I'd echo the contrast/comparison (which is after all the entire *purpose* of OP's text).